# Is it possible to place custom metadata in the offset Number in a scheduled path in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled

I have a question about whether it is possible to place a variable in the offset number in the scheduled path? A Variable that can be modified outside the flow to avoid stopping the flow and modified it when is in production? I use this schedule path to send an email alert 31 days before the end working date. Can it be performed with apex? Or practically that requirement cannot be accomplished?
[image]

Comment: @Felix van Hove Thank you for the review and edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about this from the wrong direction.

You can create a new Custom Field (Formula), and specify the metadata:

## (Warning End Date): Returns Date

```
EndWorkingDate__c - $CustomMetadata.TimeDelay__mdt.DefaultValue.Offset__c
```

Then, in your Flow, specify (0 Days Before) (Warning_End_Date__c). A word of caution, though; records that are saved before the offset value are changed will not honor the new date unless they are edited before the scheduled path executes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and explanation, I was not aware that you can use a formula field to place it like that, I have a lot to learn about it